# How to puppetize gem install specific to puppet's ruby?

Tags: puppet, ruby, gem

The Puppet Azure module requires specific gems to be installed.  The directions https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-azure show the following example:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem install azure azure_mgmt_compute azure_mgmt_storage azure_mgmt_resources azure_mgmt_network  hocon retries --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

The specific gem binary `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem` is used to ensure the gems are installed to the puppet install directory and use puppet's bundled version of ruby.

Puppet's package resource has a gem provider but it will install using the system ruby.

How can I puppetize the gem install specific to puppet?  I prefer not to use an `exec` resource.  Is there a resource for puppet-agent to install gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/4.0.0/type.html#package-provider-puppet_gem

New for Puppet v4 is a puppet_gem provider to the package resource.

```
package { 'azure' :
  provider => 'puppet_gem',
  ensure   => installed,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the provider](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/b13322138aa256e6bb939dd78893a7b1b4455f0a/lib/puppet/provider/package/gem.rb#L18) it does indeed shell out to `gem` instead of doing things in-ruby (which is probably not possible at all).

This is not configurable. You can try and make the puppet `agent` (or `apply`) run with a `PATH` that prefers Puppet's Ruby/gem over other copies. That might do it (but might break other things). Of course, you loose the option to install "system" gems in the same Puppet transaction.